# Some .js files load from server, others dont. No errors

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc and iis 7 to host some javascript files. I have a simple webpage (in a different domain, but the effect is the same if I serve the page from my own domain) with the following script tags:

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script scr="http://www.example.com/Scripts/MYJSFILE.js"></script>
```

JQuery loads just fine, where as MYJSFILE does not load at all. I recieve no error in the console, making this hard to investigate. If I enter "http://www.example.com/Scripts/MYJSFILE.js" into the browser, I get the js file in plain text, as though it is being served correctly.
Any help/thoughts on this would be fantastic.

Comment: Please provide your real domain address, not 'example.com', and your real script to check for errors. It's not possible to investigate your problem with the existing information.

Comment: stack exchange doesn't let you supply real domains

Comment: Your level not allows you to provide it as link, but you can write it as a plain text.